# Use an ObjC Block as a callback for CGDataProviderCreateWithData

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, core-graphics, objective-c-blocks

We want to call `CGDataProviderCreateWithData()` with the `releaseData` callback defined right in the arguments list. How can we do it?

I've tried a bunch of options, but was unable to crack the block syntax for this case.

The following:

```
const CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(
    NULL,
    outputPixelDataBytes,
    pixelsSize,
    ^void(void * __nullable info, const void * data, size_t size) {
        free(data);
    });
```

doesn't compile with the error:

> Passing 'void (^)(void * _Nullable, const void *, size_t)' to
>   parameter of incompatible type 'CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback
>   _Nullable' (aka 'void (*)(void * _Nullable, const void * _Nonnull, unsigned long)')

Not sure what to change to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGDataProviderCreateWithData()` does not take a block, it takes a function pointer, which is a different type of thing. You can't define a function inline like you're trying to do. You will have to define the function out-of-line and pass its address:

```
static void MyReleaseCallback(void * __nullable info, const void *  data, size_t size)
{
    free(data);
}

...
{
    ...
    const CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(
        NULL,
        outputPixelDataBytes,
        pixelsSize,
        MyReleaseCallback);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did exactly as you suggested, but now it says: `Incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type 'void (void *, void *, size_t)' (aka 'void (void *, void *, unsigned long)')to a CF function expecting 'CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback _Nullable' (aka 'void (*)(void * _Nullable, const void * _Nonnull, unsigned long)') type`. Again, I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: My mistake for trusting the documentation rather than the header file. I have edited my answer to fix the signature of the `MyReleaseCallback()` function to match the actual declaration of `CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback`.

Comment: Thank you! It's compiling now. Gosh, ObjC syntax is just nuts. What still bothers me is the warning on `free()` line. It's due to we can't drop `const` in `const void *  data` param declaration, since it'll lead to the same compile error. Not sure even why it's declared as `const` in their sources, since [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdataproviderreleasedatacallback?language=objc) explicitly say: `You may safely modify, move, or release your provider data at this time.` Apparently, manual cast is our best friend with Apple APIs.

Comment: This isn't ObjC, but straight C and, yes, function pointers have always been a bit .... tedious. :)